# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: d.e.a.e.b.<init> [interface c.p.i, class android.content.Context]

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-appcompat

I have an app now published on the play store. In debug, the app runs perfectly but when I tried to download the release app crashes instantly and it gives me this error.

```
2021-03-04 15:02:40.195 15100-15100/com.uhi5d.spotibud E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.uhi5d.spotibud, PID: 15100
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uhi5d.spotibud/com.uhi5d.spotibud.load.ContentActivity}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: d.e.a.e.b.<init> [interface c.p.i, class android.content.Context]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3459)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2046)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: d.e.a.e.b.<init> [interface c.p.i, class android.content.Context]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
    at d.e.a.e.a.a(CustomViewModelFactory.kt:10)
    at c.p.u.b(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at c.p.u.a(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.uhi5d.spotibud.load.ContentActivity.onCreate(ContentActivity.kt:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7916)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7903)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3285)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3459) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2046) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

My ViewModel factory

```
public class CustomViewModelFactory(val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,public val context: Context):ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return modelClass.getConstructor(LifecycleOwner::class.java,Context::class.java).newInstance(lifecycleOwner,context)
}
```

}

And error part

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content)

    // ViewModel components
    factory = CustomViewModelFactory(this,this)
    viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory!!).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: You need to annotate your ViewModel constructor with `@Keep` so it doesn’t get removed by Proguard. Proguard is probably optimizing it away without realizing you’re calling it because you are calling the constructor so abstractly with reflection only.

Comment: thanks for the help. seems like my style is wrong and I have to change lots of code.

Comment: Adding `@Keep` is easy. For any of your ViewModels that use this provider, add `@Keep constructor` right before the constructor. For example: change `class MyViewModel(owner: LifecycleOwner, context: Context)` to `class MyViewModel @Keep constructor(owner: LifecycleOwner, context: Context)`

Comment: it worked. Thank you so much.